# Name That ...Name? 11

Tags: riddle, knowledge

I ban a Christmas meal for a religious reason

I am given some torque for anti-Semitic treason

Drop the last letter for a pizza topping less seen

Of Latin is where this bole of a name hit the scene

Name the Name

Comment: At mention of the pizza topping, I was gonna say Rot13(Byvire) where you can drop the first *or* last letter for some pizza topping (the first being associated with Rot13(puvpxra)). Unfortunately, [the origin of] this name doesn't fit the other lines. Nice riddle, though! $(+1)$ :D

Comment: Xavier, is the name not the one given by this answer (or the first name specifically)? Not sure if this bounty is still available to be claimed

Comment: Sorry, the first name is correct. Forgetting to mark the check is a bit of a bad habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer:

> Oliver Cromwell?

I ban Christmas for a religious reason

> Being a puritan

I am given torque for some anti-semitic treason

> Signed the death warrant for Charles the first

Drop the last letter for a pizza topping not seen

> Oliver to olive

Of Latin is where this bole name hit the scene

> On a coin, there was a Latin inscription translating to: Oliver, by the Grace of God of the Republic of England, Scotland and Ireland etc. Protector

Comment: No, I did not take that from user477343 I had no clue until I finished and translated from rot13 in case you thought I was

Answer (score 0):

Purely from the first clue I think it's

> Oliver Cromwell, because he famously did this.

Comment: I believe this answer has already been given and was accepted several days ago (see above). In general we encourage posting of new answers to problems rather than repeats. Great answer though! :)

Comment: @El-Guest sorry didn't realise. Saw it had a bounty and knew the answer so didn't look at others, will check in future.

Comment: No worries! It is a correct guess, at any rate so kudos to you for determining it!